# scripting- Ignoring a variable when undefined

Tags: ksh, variable

HP-UX *** B.11.31 U ia64 **** unlimited-user license
Hello,

```
var1=abc
var2=xyz
touch $var1 $var2 $var3
```

if the one of the variable is not set the command fails with

```
ksh: var3: parameter not set
```

How do we make the command ignore the variable that is not set/defined and create the files for the variables that are defined.
Without if loops. Just within the touch command.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd get that error message if you had turned the `-u` option either by invoking `ksh` as `ksh -u` or `ksh -o nounset` or by running `set -u` or `set -o nounset`.

```
touch $var1 $var2 $var3
```

is wrong anyway unless those variables are meant to contain lists of file patterns.

It should have been:

```
touch -- "$var1" "$var2" "$var3"
```

Now, if you want to allow one of them to be empty and not pass it as an empty argument to `touch` in that case (and work around `set -u`),  you'd write:

```
touch -- ${var1:+"$var1"} ${var2:+"$var2"} ${var3:+"$var3"}
```

Another option is to do:

```
(IFS=; set -f +u; touch -- $var1 $var2 $var3)
```

With `IFS=`, we disable *word splitting*, with `set -f` globbing, but we rely on the third side-effect of leaving variables unquoted: *empty removal*. (and we also disable `nounset` with `set +u`, all of that in a subshell only).

Answer (score 0):

I doubt if you can do it just in a line, you can try something like this

```
validate_touch()
{
for value in "$@"
do
if [ ! -z "$value" ]; then touch $value;fi
done
}
validate_touch new
```

Comment: what about the colon and hyphen combination ":-"

Comment: it(colon hyphen) is used to get a default value when the variable is not defined. can we set that to nothing?

Comment: In that case, you'd have to add an elif condition to ignore that as well. Are there a limited number of combinations you'd like to ignore?